# Maintain separate read/unread status for multiple users in one Outlook mailbox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, user-accounts, imap, microsoft-outlook-2016

We have multiple people using a single mailbox (email address) in Outlook,
accessing it from different PCs. 
How can we maintain read/unread status of messages
independently for each person? 
So, if mail comes to xyz@example.com, and person A opens it,
then when person B and C open the mailbox (in Outlook),
they see that message as unread?

Comment: The question is not really clear

Comment: I can only guess that using POP3 rather than IMAP would do what you want, but your question really is unclear :-(

Comment: Not using the same email address on multiple PCs would easily accomplish what you are describing.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? We are facing the same issue where I work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Outlook doesn’t natively support such a capability.

1. As was mentioned in a comment, your life might be easier
   if you didn’t have multiple users sharing a mailbox. 
   But I guess if this is something like `help@your-company.com`
   or `support@your-company.com`, it might be the best way to do it.

It’s not clear from your question
whether you want *every* message to be read by *everybody*,
or whether you want every message to be handled by *somebody*,
so, if person A reads a message and doesn’t handle it,
persons B and C will know that the message hasn’t handled it.

2. If you want *every* message to be read by *everybody*,
   your best bet may be to use different software. 
   Many years ago I used Lotus Notes,
   and I recall that it had a capability like this.
3. If you want every message to be handled by *somebody*,

   - Train your users to manually mark a message as unread
     if they read it and don’t handle it.
   - Create a “Handled” folder,
     and train your users to manually move messages to that folder
     when they’ve been handled.
   - Investigate the possibility of automating one of the above options
     with VBA.